# Resource modules from a course in MOODLE3.5

Tags: moodle

What would be the best way to track resource modules from a course.

Here is my attempt, but not satisfied from specifying resource id's.

```
SELECT cmc.coursemoduleid
FROM mdl_course_modules_completion cmc 
JOIN mdl_course_modules cm ON cm.id = cmc.coursemoduleid
JOIN mdl_modules m ON m.id= cm.module
WHERE cm.deletioninprogress=0 
AND m.id IN (1,3,8,11,12,15,17,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using (INNER) JOIN you may strict results by course id like this:

```
    SELECT cmc.coursemoduleid
    FROM mdl_course_modules_completion cmc 
    JOIN mdl_course_modules cm ON cm.id = cmc.coursemoduleid AND cm.course = YOURCOURSEID
    JOIN mdl_modules m ON m.id= cm.module
    WHERE cm.deletioninprogress=0 AND m.name IN ('resource', 'page', 'url')
```

*UPDATE*

The info about module being a resource is not stored in database. But you may explicitly point out all module names you are interested in. The only downside is, if you decide to install new resource third party module you'll have to update your SQL

Comment: Thank You for the answer. It shows all the modules within a course(activity & resource), but I'm looking for only resource modules.